# SQL SUM + Distinct

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to know the request with which I displayed the sum of the amounts of the various clients that do not repeat with the SUM function and DISTINCT.

***I used :***

```
SELECT DISTINCT id_721z, SUM(montant) AS somme_montant 
FROM `roue_ventes_cb` 
WHERE `date_transaction` between '2015/01/01' and '2015/01/21';
```

But the result is not displayed correctly. I have this data:

id_721z |   montant

```
1   |   15
1   |   15
2   |   22
2   |   22
2   |   22
```

I would like to show total_montant = 37 but not

id_721z |   montant

```
1   |   30
2   |   66
```

Comment: Could you sample output and explain why it is incorrect? Consider using  sqlfiddle.com

Comment: The total amount is inflated because of that repeat customers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(montant) AS somme_montant
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT id_721z, montant
    FROM `roue_ventes_cb`
    WHERE `date_transaction` between '2015/01/01' and '2015/01/21'
) AS t
```

Comment: watching my response at the top of your answer

Comment: @Ayedmedamine: If you want 37 the answer of eumiro is right.

Answer (score 2):

This will sum all different montants. But if two ids have the same montant it will only count it once.

```
SELECT id_721z, SUM(DISTINCT montant) AS somme_montant 
FROM `roue_ventes_cb` 
WHERE `date_transaction` between '2015/01/01' and '2015/01/21';
```

So I will prefer emiros answer in any case. It is safer and distint will have a performance penalty anyway.